# Dataflow job failed - "Resource worker_pool_resource failed to shut down"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What does the following error mean?

```
Jan 12, 2016, 11:07:12 AM
(8e14844346add98d): Workflow failed. Causes: (8e14844346addb8e): Step teardown_resource_global_gce_worker_pool535: Resource worker_pool_resource failed to shut down
```

It would suggest to me that the worker pool for my Dataflow job could not be shut down, however when when I check VM resources there are no VMs running.

We've only started to get this error since since enabling autoscaling.

**With autoscaling enabled, this error appeared 3 times in succession:**

- 2016-01-11_15_02_03-7824848657076347150
- 2016-01-11_18_19_05-12071780534123998465
- 2016-01-11_20_47_50-3984152789115879104

**Prior to enabling autoscaling we never saw this error e.g:**

- 2016-01-11_00_07_35-8990559652869485300
- 2016-01-10_19_10_43-1317798560931071006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dataflow service returns this error when it cannot be sure that the machines were shut down successfully.  For example, if the shutdown request returns an unexpected error type, the failure is reported so that users can potentially take action rather than incur costs from idle machines.

In this case, the service is hitting a quota limit when attempting to resize the worker pool.  To work around this issue, you can set --maxNumWorkers to a value under your maximum Compute Engine quota to prevent this from happening.

Comment: It's interesting that only since we've enabled autoscaling we start to see this error. Could it be that it's a problem isolated when autoscaling is enabled? I've added some job ids as examples.

Comment: It's likely a coincidence, but we're investigating.

Comment: I don't think it's a quota issue Sam. Our quota allows us to spin up 2000 cores. This jobs are way under that. Additionally, when I run it *without* autoscaling enabled e.g. 50 VMs, then we get no errors. But if we run with autoscaling enabled with a ceiling value of 50 VMs, then we get the error. That doesn't make sense right?

Comment: It's a disk quota issue, not a CPU quota issue, according to what we're seeing.

Comment: found the problem - we were calling the wrong method to set the max number of workers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34779509/cloud-dataflow-job-scaling-beyond-max-worker-value/34782203#34782203